# http://localhost works but 127.0.0.1 does not work in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, localhost, xampp

I am running xampp on windows 7. When I do `http://localhost`, I get the xampp welcome screen in my web browser but `http://127.0.0.1` does not work. In my windows hosts file, I have uncommented `127.0.0.1 localhost` but the problem still exists. I have checked to see if firewall is blocking anything but still no good results.

How do I resolve this problem.

Comment: I believe xampp does not accept the ip address to be used but only localhost. You should look into this from the xampp side first.

Comment: So then what is wrong with xampp? I think it is normal for xampp to accept 127.0.0.1. It was stated in the readme file of the installation package.